Why is this undefined type guard not working?
Is the TypeScript compiler right here?
const someFunction = (s: string | undefined, b: boolean) => {
  if (!s && b){
    return;
  } else if (!s && !b) {
    return;
  }

  // Typescript thinks s can be undefined here
  s.charAt(1)
}

Link to the same code in TS Playground
This code seems so simple that I believe the TS compiler should understand it.

The actually "simple" version of that is more like this playground link which TS handles fine. While a human being has no trouble with your code, TS doesn't and cannot keep track of every correlation among sets of variables, so it doesn't really try. See the linked q/a above, and GitHub issues like ms/TS#56221 and issues linked within.

The issue here is that TypeScript's type inference doesn't realize that in the else branch, s is guaranteed to be a string (i.e., not undefined). The conditions you set in the first two branches ensure that by the time the else is reached, s must be a string because the two return statements handle cases where s is undefined. However, TypeScript doesn't automatically infer this. You can either use a type assertion or an additional check to satisfy TypeScript's type system.
const someFunction = (s: string | undefined, b: boolean) => {
  if (!s && b) {
    return;
  } else if (!s && !b) {
    return;
  }
  // Here i added ! after s
  s!.charAt(1);
}

or
const someFunction = (s: string | undefined, b: boolean) => {
  if (!s && b) {
    return;
  } else if (!s && !b) {
    return;
  }

  // Check again if s is defined
  if (s !== undefined) {
    s.charAt(1);
  }
}

